# TLS sslv3 hankshake error

Tags: api, ssl, tcl, sslv3

I use a Tcl script to pull from several API's and all of a sudden some API's stopped working. eg:

```
set data [http_call_get https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/popular?page=1&anchor=1]
```

responds with the error:

> SSL Channel "sock624": error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

It's odd that two of the five API's from different sites stopped working within an hour or each other so I feel that something changed with the compatibility of the tls1.6.3.1 tcl package which binding with "::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket"

I've tried on three different machines (2 x Windows and a ubuntu box).

Comment: note: it still works requesting some https like https://www.yahoo.com

Comment: I am not familiar with the package, but is there a question? Or maybe you could add it at the end of your post?

Comment: It might be a Certificate Authority problem.

Comment: I presented an error, Jerry. I was looking for an answer which other people figured out quite fast. Here's your question: Do you troll this site to post statements with question marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sites you are attempting to connect to have probably disabled sslv3 due to the poodle vulnerability.

I would guess your tcl script needs to use TLS instead.

Comment: Thank you Levi. This is correct. I was able to pass tls1 when registering the package with the http package. eg:                               http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]